# Restarting a spring batch job that is run by multiple threads

Tags: spring-batch, restart, throttling

We have a requirement where we read from a file, porocess it and write to a flat file. My question is would FlatFileItemReader keep track of the records it processed so that if job fails in the middle it can pick up where it failed.

For example let's say the throttle limit is 2 and commit-interval is 10 and my file has 20 records. Let's say thread1 is processing 1st 10 records and 
thread2 is processing next 10 records. If all 10 records by thread2 are processed succesfully and thread1 failed because of one bad record and hence the entire job failed. Next time 
when the job is restarted how the spring would identify unprocessed records?

What is a better way to process the file using multiple threads and at the same time be able to start over when failed in the middle.

```
<batch:job job-repository="jobRepository" id="insertIntoCsvFromCsvJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager"
                task-executor="taskExecutor" throttle-limit="${throttle-limit}">
                <batch:chunk reader="csvFileItemReader" writer="customWriter" processor="compositeProcessor
                    commit-interval="${commit-interval}" >
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="csvFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
         <property name="resource" value="classpath:files/input.csv" />         
        <property name="lineMapper" ref="fieldSetMapper" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="csvFileItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
        <property name="resource" value="file:c:/outout.csv" />
        <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />
        <property name="lineAggregator" ref="lineAggregator" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not.

I would even say that your code will break sooner or later. The problem is that the read (respectively the write method) of the FlatFileItemReader (respectively  FlatFileItemWriter) is not threadsafe.

If you want to use them asynchronously, you need to implement a wrapper ItemWriter and ItemReader, that synchronizes the calls to the FlatFileItemReader/Writer.

But of course, the whole restarting in the middle will not work, since the order of the chunks is not guaranteed if you use just the standard implementation of FlatFileItemReader/Writer. The problem is that a chunk could overtake another chunk, causing the read-position-pointer in the execution context moving after the chunk that was overtaken. But if the chunk that was overtaken fails, the position in the execution context would indicate that the entries of the failed chunks had been processed successfully.

Of course, you could also implement your logic in an adapter, where you keep track of the processed entries and only move the position pointer forward when you know, that all previous entries had been processed and had been written.